# C++ Not sure how to have my program output the location of a space

Tags: c++, string, encryption

Alright, so I have two questions and if anyone can help me out I would greatly appreciate it!  This is my first programming class, so it would also be my first C++ class and I'm a bit stuck.

So I created a Caesar cipher that shifts the string that the user inputs to the right by a pseudo random number between 8-15.  What the complete program needs to do is give the number it is shifted by at the beginning, followed by the encrypted string.  If there are spaces in the string that are inputed, they need to take the letter/number that is before the space and shift it by 4.  I need to terminate the encryption with an '&' character and that is followed by a '#' character and then the number location of the first space followed by another '#' character and another location of a second space if there is one and so on.

So for example, if I were encrypting a string that was being shifted by 9 and said:

```
Hello World 123
```

It should look like this when encrypted:

```
9qnuuxsfxaumh012&#6#12
```

1. My first and more important question.  I can't figure out how to make the program output the '#' character followed by the number that tells the location of the space.  I've thought of maybe doing some kind of loop that reads the string but I'm coming up blank.  If I could get some advice that would be great as this is the only part holding me up from turning this in.
2. My second question comes from a little confusion within my own code that I would love an English interpretation on how it works since I don't understand it myself.  I was first using just for loops to make it so that the character 'z' would wrap back around to 'a' but no matter what I did, I kept getting it to only wrap around after a '{' character which is the next character after 'z' on the ascii table.  So I decided to change my method and I read on wikipedia under "Caesar cipher" that you could use a modulus.  So I used the equation they gave me which was E(x) = (a + b) mod 26.   Well it didn't work.  So I started to do a google search and saw 2 different posts where people subtracted the character 'a' and then added the chracter 'a' back on at the end as well as added the variable to itself with +=.  So I put it in and it worked.
   It looks like this:

   ```
   output += ((input[count] - 'a' + n) % 26) + 'a';
   ```

and I thought it would look like this after reading the wiki and it not working when i put this in

```
    output = ((input[count] + n) % 26)
```

Same goes for wrapping the numbers as well:

```
output += ((input[count] - '0' + n) % 10) + '0';
```

So if someone could explain to me why I am adding output to itself as well as subtracting 'a' in the beginning and then re-adding 'a' at the end so I could understand what's going on.  I really don't like having code in a program that I'm going to turn in that I don't even understand myself.

Anyways, I'm sorry for the long read, I just thought I would explain what's going on and what I need clearly so that anyone willing to help would completely understand what I'm saying without me having to follow up with a second post explaining.

And finally here's the full program that I have written:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

//random number generator between 8 and 15
int random()
{
    int value;
    value = rand() % (18 - 10) + 8;
    return value;
}

int main()

{
    //Give random() a seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    //Declare variables
    string input;
    int length;
    int n = random();
    string output;

    //Program
    cout << "Enter your secret message: " << endl;
    getline (cin, input);
    cout << n;

    length = input.length();

    for (int count = 0; count < length; count++)
    {
        input[count] = tolower(input[count]);
        if (input[count] >= 'a' && input[count] <= 'z')
        {
            output += ((input[count] - 'a' + n) % 26) + 'a';
        }
        if (input[count] >= '0' && input[count] <= '9')
        {
            output += ((input[count] - '0' + n) % 10) + '0';
        }
        else if(input[count] == ' ')
        {
            if (input[count - 1] >= 'a' && input[count - 1] <= 'z')
            {
                output += ((input[count - 1] - 'a' + 4) % 26) + 'a';
            }
            else if (input[count - 1] >= '0' && input[count - 1] <= '9')
            {
                output += ((input[count - 1] - '0' + 4) % 10) + '0';
            }
            cout << output;
        }
    }
            cout << output << endl;
            return 0;   
}
```

Thanks so much for anyone willing to help!

Comment: `((input[count] + n) % 26)` will generate an  number between 0 and 25, not a `char` between `a` and `z`. Thus why that doesn't work. You're missing a character-base.

Comment: That makes sense, but if that were the case, then why do I need to do the same for the numbers?  If it would give me a number back, why do I need to subtract 0, and then add 0 back on at the end in order for it to work.  Also, why do I have to put a += symbol instead of just an = symbol.  And lastly, why would subtracting the specific character 'a' and adding the specific character 'a' turn everything into a character between 'a' and 'z'?  Sorry, I just really want to understand.

Comment: Read the answers below.

Comment: If all spaces embed locations are to include in a single list *after* all the output is calculated, i don't see how what you have here would work for part 1. I would strongly advise you test it with something that is non-trivial input.

Comment: yes, I just found that out after testing it with numbers and it gives me a lot of stuff I didn't ask for.  It worked when I just put in "Hello World" :(.  So, I need to use a stringstream then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of the seemingly odd expansion is to do the following:

- Create a number from 0..25: `input[count] - 'a'`
- Adjust that number by adding your shift amount:   `+ n`
- Modulo the result with 26 to wrap overflow of 26+ back into 0..25:  `% 26`
- And finally, add that result back to the base character: `+`a``

Your idea of a shortcut:

```
output = ((input[count] + n) % 26)
```

simply takes the ascii value of the input char, adds the shift, then modulo 26. The result is a value in 0..25, nowhere near the range of `'a'..'z'`.

And before you think just adding `'a'` would work, it isn't that simple. For example, suppose you had a shift of 9 and in input char of `'z'`

The presented formula that works: `(ch - 'a' + n) % 26 + 'a'`

```
(('z' - 'a' + 9) % 26 + 'a'
((122 - 97 + 9) % 26 + 97
34 % 26 + 97
8 + 97
105, the ascii value of 'i'
```

Your formula, with `'a'` adjustment: `(ch + n) % 26 + 'a'`

```
('z' + 9) % 26 + 'a'
(122 + 9) % 26 + 97
131 % 26 + 97
1 + 97
98, the ascii value for 'b'.
```

The problem is the distance from the beginning of the char sequence that is being modulo-adjusted is never accounted for in the modulo reduction. Thus the reason for the formula you find odd.

---

Regarding how to accumulate a list of space locations. a `ostringstream` will make that *trivial*, as would a `std::vector<int>`. An example of the former looks like this:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream> // for std::ostringstream
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    //Give random() a seed
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(NULL)));

    //Declare variables
    string input;
    int length;
    int n = rand() % (18 - 10) + 8;
    string output;

    //Program
    cout << "Enter your secret message: " << endl;
    getline (cin, input);
    cout << n;

    // string stream to hold the list of space locations.
    std::ostringstream oss;

    length = input.length();

    for (int count = 0; count < length; count++)
    {
        input[count] = tolower(input[count]);
        if (input[count] >= 'a' && input[count] <= 'z')
        {
            output += ((input[count] - 'a' + n) % 26) + 'a';
        }
        if (input[count] >= '0' && input[count] <= '9')
        {
            output += ((input[count] - '0' + n) % 10) + '0';
        }
        else if(input[count] == ' ')
        {
            if (input[count - 1] >= 'a' && input[count - 1] <= 'z')
            {
                output += ((input[count - 1] - 'a' + 4) % 26) + 'a';
            }
            else if (input[count - 1] >= '0' && input[count - 1] <= '9')
            {
                output += ((input[count - 1] - '0' + 4) % 10) + '0';
            }

            // add space location with preamble to string stream
            oss << '#' << count;
        }
    }

    // append space accumulated list string to the end after '&'
    cout << output << '&' << oss.str() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you by chance know how I would get the answer to my first question? I don't need someone to write the code out for me. I just really need a strong step in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @Cush done. That is one way to do it. there are others, but that one is so trivial it is near-laughable. Best of luck.

Comment: I'm going to have to open up my book and skip ahead to read up on and understand how a stringstream works since I don't remember us ever going over what that is in class.  Thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Cush Think of it as a file stream like `std:cout` that you dump stuff in to, but it writes to an in-memory expandable string buffer rather than disk or a console. Once you're done, you can extract your formatted data via the `str()` member. They come in handy sometimes (as you can see). *Learn the standard library*. I can't stress that enough. Its *amazing* how much more fluid and creative your programs can be when you are utilizing the warehouse of wheels already invented by a rack of very intelligent people. Anyway, all the best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Two answer the second question:

```
input[count] - 'a'
```

This gives you 0 for the letter a, 1 for the letter b, ... 25 for the letter z.

```
input[count] - 'a' + n
```

Then you add the number n. Having "a" as an input and being n==2 you will get a 3. But for a "z" as input you will get a 27.

To solve the problem you use the modulus:

```
(input[count] - 'a' + n) % 26
```

The result is a 1 for the "z".

```
((input[count] - 'a' + n) % 26) + 'a'
```

Now you transfer the number from 0 to 25 back to the corresponding ASCII code.

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help!  Do you by chance know how I would get the answer to my first question?  I don't need someone to write the code out for me.  I just really need a strong step in the right direction.  Thanks!

Comment: Give us some code. What did you try to solve the problem of the first question? You already have the "count" variable in your for loop you just have to save this value whenever you see a space.

Comment: nevermind, I'm dumb >.<  I figured it out.  Was really easy, will edit first post with what I did

Comment: Oh and also, could you tell me why, for the second question, I need to use += instead of just =?

Comment: Can you post the solution anyway?

Comment: I posted it at the end of my OP.

Comment: Oh and I understand what += means, I'm just curious why I need to add output inside my output statement.

Comment: nvm, my solution doesn't work when I add numbers in as well as when I add multiple spaces

Comment: Because otherwise you would override your previous output. As an alternative you could also execute cout << output; in each loop iteration to pass the output to the output stream.

Comment: Ah, I get what you're saying.  Thanks again.  Sorry for making you explain it further.  It's just when I learn, I need to understand exactly how everything is working so it clicks in my head and I can apply it in other areas.  Not a person who can just memorize that that sign must go there.